# Pandas - Combine df.loc for multiple operations?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Is there a way to perform one `df.loc` lookup, but then perform multiple operations on the subset of rows?

Here's the motivation. I have 2 dataframes with data on the same users. I am looping over `df_2.groupby('user_id')` and then look up on the other dataframe to assign some values:

```
for user, user_df in df_2.groupby('user_id'):
    df_1.loc[df_1.user_id == user, 'value_1'] == user_df.value_1.mean()
    df_1.loc[df_1.user_id == user, 'value_2'] == user_df.value_2.min()
```

could I combine these in some way to perform just one df.loc, but assign both values?

Comment: It would be helpful to provide samples of your two dataframes, such as `df_1.head(10)` and `df_2.head(10)`

Answer (score 1):

You can align indices, then use the *in-place* [`pd.DataFrame.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
df_1 = df_1.set_index('user_id')
df_1.update(df_2.groupby('user_id')[['value_1', 'value_2']].mean())
```

Notice this also obviates the need for a Python-level `for` loop.

Comment: The problem here is that the summary operation is not as flexible as I need it -- e.g. it has to be a `.mean()` for all columns.

Comment: Then just use `df_2.groupby('user_id', as_index=False).mean()` ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure the following would work:

```
grouped = df_2.groupby('user_id').agg({'value1': 'mean', 'value2': 'min'})
df_1 = df_1.merge(grouped, left_on='user_id', right_index=True, sort=False)
```

This requires that `value1` and `value2` not be in `df_1`, else you'll have duplicate columns. If that's a potential issue, use `df_1 = df_1.drop(columns=['value1', 'value2'], errors='ignore')` prior to merging.